# How to add a TabbarController using phone gap for iPhone App

Tags: iphone, cordova, tabbarcontroller

I am making a iPhone app using phone gap in that I want to add a tab bar Controller either using HTML or by using native components to it. Can anyone suggest to me how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using phonegap/cordova versions 1.5+ you can create a native tabbar with this plugin: https://github.com/AndiDog/phonegap-ios-tabbar-plugin

Other phonegap/cordova plugins can be found here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS

Here's a tutorial how to implement this: http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/03/using-the-native-tabbar-plugin-in-cordova/

This is of course the best approach. Other one would be to use a jQuery Mobile and create a HTML tabbar. This is a harder way because it will take time to style it properly and even then it would not fully act as a native tabbar.

Comment: No, but Android has its own native tabbar plugin. I don't know about blackberry.